# facebook comments plugin html iframe content getting clipped, doesnt stretch in a container

Tags: html, css, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello I am unable to stretch an iframe to display it's entire content.

Consider this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nDz32/

the content is clipped and I can't scroll down to see the rest of the comments.

Now consider this:

where I have just removed  `height: 100% !important`

http://jsfiddle.net/rASW7/1/

I can scroll through all the comments.

#### Problem:

This doesn't work in an actual browser. In a browser like Chrome the content is clipped regardless of what I set. I need to have it stretch 100% in every direction as I am to embed it in a webview on a mobile device.

I am helpless I tried every combination I could think of and yet I can't get it to display like it does in the second link inside an actual browser...

Comment: Question, which I guess doesn't matter, why wrap the FB comments. Why not let them work as designed. If I remember right they switch to a mobile minimal interface on mobile devices. Scrolling within a scrolled page is a crappy UI. While I wish I had an answer, I don't.

Comment: Doesn't matter if I use the mobile or desktop comments. Either way the content is clipped and I can't see the rest. Perhaps I am doing something wrong but I have already lost my mind with this :/... Basically I need an empty page and display those comments on the entire screen. Mobile or desktop doesn't matter, but as simple as it  sounds I failed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this on my site. Does this work for you?

Replace yours with this:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments span, .fb-comments.fb_iframe_widget span iframe  {width: 100% !important; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nDz32/1/

Looks like the issue was local files using the SDK get resized incorrectly even with CSS styling.

Comment: When I paste it to a html file and open with Chrome (31.0.1650.63) just 1/4 of content is visible :( Same happens on the mobile browser. For some reason JSFiddle displays it correctly, but it doesn't render like that on an actual browser.

Comment: http://oi43.tinypic.com/2emfx9u.jpg - looks like this, not to mention no scrolling works.

Comment: On my website. The only CSS I added at all for the FB Comments that code. I don't have a wrapper but I added a wrapper to test just now and it works just fine.

Comment: It will only show as much code as your wrapper allows. You need overflow: scroll on your wrapper. Do you want your wrapper to be the same height as your iframe? Or do you want your wrapper to limit the iframe height and scroll within that?

Comment: Nope, no dice :/ Mind pasting a jsfiddle so I could copy paste it to see? Btw what OS/Browser are you on?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? A set width/height wrapper that limits the width/height of the FB frame? Or do you want to dynamically size an iframe based on its content. Or are you trying to change the wrapper size based on the iframe content?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rASW7/1/ - Here, imagine that the box the content is displayed in is the browser window or a mobile device screen. You can see I can freely scroll to see content beyond the screen at the bottom. Now when I take the same thing and paste into a .html file and open it it's nowhere near as functional. I am attempting to set heights and widths everywhere to 100% since it's supposed to stretch to as big the window/mobile screen is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nDz32/3/ Sorry. I mistyped something. Plus I added color so you can see the wrapper.

Comment: The third one is basically what I want. I took the code and slapped it in a .html file and opened from the file system, but it's broken, though and that's what haunts me : (. It displays/works ok in jsfiddle, but not from the file system.

Comment: What size is your wrapper on your dev page. There has to be some CSS somewhere sizing it. Can you use FireBug and get the styles and show me,

Comment: here's what I am attempting to open from the file system: http://pastebin.com/SuZYqNeQ

Comment: great give me a moment

Comment: So what is happening when I inspect the element is the span has a set height. Mine on my page does too but it's taller. It's not set via CSS, it's almost like it's set via javascript. Let me play a bit.

Comment: Could it be that on your webpage you reference a different version of the sdk? Might try to replace the URL for the SDK and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that it's doing something because of the fact that it's a local file vs a web file. It's doing the same thing on mine as well, but there is no reason to. It may be because FB cannot access data from the page to resize itself because the page is local. It may use something like postMessage. I'm going to put the exact same code on my koding server and check. stand by.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43635/discussion-between-leeish-and-krdx)

Comment: Sure, just did. Thank you again:)